# Can I use select query in aws redshift python udf function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How I can execute a select query in AWS Redshift UDF using plpythonu like oracle function with select into class in function like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf(id varchar(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
STABLE
AS $$
   result = plpy.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM abc")
   return result
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

when I run above function i got following error.

```
ERROR: XX000: NameError: global name 'plpy' is not defined. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

It's available on Postgresql (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpython-database.html).

At present, Amazon Redshift is not supported.

Same question like yours on this url: 
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1IHV1G67CY53T/Introduction-to-Python-UDFs-in-Amazon-Redshift

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [aws](/questions/tagged/aws) [amazon-redshift](/questions/tagged/amazon-redshift)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is better to place a full answer here instead of links. If the link stops working, the answer is lost.

Comment: Thanks for your comment